# Testing a react native app on android real device

Tags: react-native, testing, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Is there a way to test a react native app on android device instead of using an emulator? For the configuration, I tried setting the deviceName as the name of my device but it didn't work out.

This is the error message:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4723
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16)

Answer (score 0):

- try to connect to 1 wifi from PC and mobile.
- launch from android studio you device instead of emulator
- adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
- reload app